# Is there a maximum height or width for an HTML document?

Tags: html, css

I am thinking about converting a PDF document into a long scrolling HTML doc (my reason is that there is video in the document and we want to turn the video into streaming rather than require anyone viewing the presentation to download 200+mb before being able to view anything). I am wondering if there is a maximum pixel width or height to HTML documents, or if browsers start to have difficulty with the DOM at certain lengths. If I convert the whole presentation to HTML it would be about 41,000 px. Does that seem reasonable? Are there limits to the pixel height or width of documents? Or best practices considerations I should keep in mind?

Comment: Have you seen http://worlds-highest-website.com/ or http://worm.bluesfear.com/index.php?content=submissions&action=view? Modern Browsers seem to render pretty big pages...

Comment: You should be designing with your users in mind. Quick, scan friendly content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, browsers can render documents of literally any size. I had a world map page that was 40,000 x 20,000 pixels, and it ran perfectly fine, even with some fairly busy JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

On IE8 and lower CSS "filter" declarations fail on anything larger than 4096 pixels. This is not a restriction on document size but can sometimes cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

It would be new to me that there is a limitation for maximum width or height of a webpage.
I have tried very big numbers and never got to a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any kind of limit, it will certanly be very slow to load 41.000px so my advice it´s not to do that...

I cant imagine someone scrolling down 41.000px, thats something almost crazy to do...

Find another way, split the video in small chapters.. chapter 1.. chapter 2..etc..